# SharePoint Online, deactivate solution - Acces denied

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template

I made several site templates, which can be found in Solutions.
[image]

I want to deactivate one(Green Grass Template), but I get this error:
[image]

Which is strange because I made the template myself, I am in the site **Owners** group, which should give me the correct roles.

I can deactivate all of the other templates, without getting this error.

Any clues?

**Edit (answer):** There was a site created from this template. After deleting that site, I could deactivate the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be a site collection administrator to do this. Add yourself to the site administrators group, and the rest shall be done as expected.

Comment: I can deactivate all of them except for 1. I am in the default "Site Owners" (full control) group for that site. I'm guessing it has something to do with the template itself?

Comment: I guess there must be an existing sub site that is created using the template. If that's the case then I believe it will not allow you deactivate it. Am assuming.. so give it a try

Comment: That's it! There was still an existing sub site made from that template. I deleted the site and then could deactivate the template. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure, glad that the solution worked out !